# Отсутствует перевод сообщения о загрузке приложения из App Store

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, мобильная-версия

При просмотре вопроса в мобильной версии сайта на iOS устройстве в верхней части страницы появляется баннер:

> [image: читать в приложении]

Если его нажать - открывается приложение Stack Exchange для iOS. Однако при этом страница успевает несколько модифицироваться. Появляется ещё одно сообщение:

> [image: Get app]

- Данное сообщение требует перевода;
- Сообщение по сути не должно отображаться, т.к. приложение уже установлено на iOS устройстве.

В качестве перевода предлагаю вариант:

> Установить через App Store

По поводу отображения сообщения об установке - [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286915/339911) на Meta.SE.

Comment: The "Get via App Store" string is [now on transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/101184801), for the other issues please refer this the post on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286915/get-via-app-store-bar)

Comment: @m0sa already did the translation!

Comment: @m0sa thank you!